# Adding an image to a button

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I have this:

[image: GUI]

Here is some code that created the above image:

```
hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
_img = wx.StaticBitmap()
_img.Create(parent, label=wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'images', 'exit-to-app.svg')))
hbox.Add(_img, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL)
_exit = wx.Button(parent, label="Exit")
_exit.SetBackgroundColour('#5968c3')
self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit, _exit)
hbox.Add(_exit, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL)
return hbox
```

How to add the bitmap to the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wx.Button` has supported adding a bitmap to the label for a while now, although on GTK builds I think it also depends on a global preference whether the icon will be displayed or not, and probably also on the active theme.  See the Button sample in the demo for an example.

https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/demo/Button.py#L28

Comment: Yes, and you can also set which side of the label where the bitmap is placed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wx.lib.buttons` library, although the buttons may be a bit plain.
However, as @RobinDunn points out, and he should know, Since version 2.9.1 wx.Button supports showing both text and an image (currently only when using wxMSW, wxGTK or OSX/Cocoa ports).

On Linux, I had to ensure that in `desktop settings` I had set `Show Icons on Buttons` or the 2nd method using just `wx.Button` didn't display the image.
Using the second method, the button look much nicer, losing that flat look.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.buttons as buts
class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        pause_button = buts.GenBitmapTextButton(self, -1, bitmap=wx.Bitmap("pause.png"), label= "Pause")
        play_button = buts.GenBitmapTextButton(self, -1, bitmap=wx.Bitmap("play.png"), label= "Play")
        time_button = wx.Button(self, -1, label= "Time")
        time_button.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap("toggle1.png"),wx.RIGHT)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        box.Add(pause_button, 0, wx.CENTER | wx.ALL,10)
        box.Add(play_button, 0, wx.CENTER | wx.ALL,10)
        box.Add(time_button, 0, wx.CENTER | wx.ALL,10)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(box)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)
        pause_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPause)
        play_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPlay)
        time_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnTime)
        self.Show()

    def OnCloseWindow(self, event):
        self.Destroy()
    def OnPause(self, event):
        print "Pause pressed"
    def OnPlay(self, event):
        print "Play pressed"
    def OnTime(self, event):
        print "Time pressed"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = TestFrame(None, -1, "wxBitmap Test")
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Added Robins new method to the answer. Thanks Robin!